# MySQL - Error Code 1054 - Unknown column al.article_id in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to execute the following query but not able to find out the issue. It keeps on complaining that

> Unknown column al.article_id in where clause

```
SELECT al.article_id, COUNT(1) 
FROM article_likes al
WHERE al.created_at > '2018-03-25 11:01:00' 
AND al.article_id 
    NOT IN (
        SELECT article_id 
        FROM article_views 
        WHERE user_id = 48 
    )
AND (
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM article_ignored AS ai 
        WHERE ai.user_id = 48 
        AND ai.article_id = al.article_id
    )
    OR 
    (
        EXISTS 
        (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM article_ignored aii 
        WHERE aii.user_id = 48 
        AND aii.article_id = al.article_id
        AND created_at > '2018-03-26 11:01:00'
        )
        AND
        EXISTS
        (
            SELECT (
                IF(al.post_type = 'article',
                (
                    SELECT DISTINCT (a.tag_id) 
                    FROM 
                    (SELECT tag_id FROM article_tags WHERE article_id = al.article_id) a
                    JOIN 
                    (SELECT tag_id FROM user_tags WHERE user_id = 48 AND type = 'interest') b
                    ON a.tag_id = b.tag_id
                ),
                (
                    SELECT DISTINCT (a.tag_id) 
                    FROM 
                    (
                    SELECT tag_id FROM article_tags 
                    WHERE article_id = (SELECT id FROM articles WHERE post_type = 'question' AND aid = al.article_id)
                    ) a
                    JOIN 
                    (SELECT tag_id FROM user_tags WHERE user_id = 48 AND type = 'interest') b
                    ON a.tag_id = b.tag_id
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
GROUP BY article_id 
ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC
LIMIT 3
```

The error is in the below section but I am not able to resolve it, can some one please help. Is this because it is nested in exists -> select -> if.

```
EXISTS
        (
            SELECT (
                IF(al.post_type = 'article',
                (
                    SELECT DISTINCT (a.tag_id) 
                    FROM 
                    (SELECT tag_id FROM article_tags WHERE article_id = al.article_id) a
                    JOIN 
                    (SELECT tag_id FROM user_tags WHERE user_id = 48 AND type = 'interest') b
                    ON a.tag_id = b.tag_id
                ),
```

Comment: Please, describe your table columns and what are you trying to do.

Comment: Are you sure, you know what you are doing? The SELECT clause is ignored in an EXISTS-subquery.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I am just using SELECT as a wrapper, if I don't use SELECT and directly write EXISTS IF(al.post_type) ... it gives syntax error

Comment: I solved it myself.. it was kind of referencing issue.. because of the multiple nesting the al.article_id was not available. I resolved it by putting the entire problematic block in the Stored Function.

Answer (score -1):

i think you may try to specify the specific colum "table.column" here:

SELECT tag_id FROM article_tags WHERE article_id = al.article_id)

to:

SELECT tag_id FROM article_tags WHERE table.article_id = al.article_id)